Card game called Sale
This game I used to play a card game that  came in a hard plastic box coloured yellow looks like a soap  box shape same size and on the top cover it said the word Sale and the bottom of the box had the instructions on how to play. I am in Australia  and the game came out in 1990s when I was in primary school. I did not know how to play the game that's why I gave it away. I can't find it online anywhere. I remember  when you closed the case it made a click sound when you closed it. I think the game was about money. I definitely  know the word is Sale on the case. There was another game in this series that was in a dark blue box they don't make them anymore I think they weren't very popular.

It's not "For Sale" by Steffan Dorra by chance?

Link to boardgame arena which might trigger memories: https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=forsale

No it was in a yellow hard plastic box looks like same shape as a rectangle soap case it made a click sound when you closed it like the sound when you close your glasses case. It is not For Sale game I think it was a kind of Trivia game inside it had writing on the back on instructions.  I am in Australia  so I think it may have been American  or Australian  it was in English writing on the bottom of the case.
